# Make a map using a splay tree

Tags: c++, tree

In my data structures and algorithms class, we were introduced to the [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree), a [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) with the additional property that recently accessed elements are quick to access (because they stay at the top of the tree until a different element is accessed).

I know that [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) uses a BST; I heard it's a [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Anyway, I thought I'd implement my own map using the splay tree idea, and I'd like to know what people think of my implementation. Does it look efficient? Is it readable?

```
#ifndef SplayTree_ms_map_h
#define SplayTree_ms_map_h

#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <exception>

namespace ms {
template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
class map {
protected:
    class Node {
    public:
        Node *llink = NULL;
        Node *rlink = NULL;
        Node *parent = NULL;
        KeyType key;
        ValueType value;

        void left_rotate() {
            assert(parent != NULL);
            assert(parent->rlink = this);

            Node *t2 = llink;
            Node *p  = parent;
            Node *gp = p->parent;

            if (gp != NULL) {
                if (gp->llink == parent) {
                    gp->llink = this;
                }
                else {
                    assert(gp->rlink = parent);
                    gp->rlink = this;
                }
                parent = gp;
            }
            else {
                parent = NULL;
            }

            p->rlink = t2;
            if (t2 != NULL) {
                p->rlink->parent = p;
            }
            llink = p;
            llink->parent = this;
        }

        void right_rotate() {
            assert(parent != NULL);
            assert(parent->llink = this);

            Node *t2 = rlink;
            Node *p  = parent;
            Node *gp = p->parent;

            if (gp != NULL) {
                if (gp->llink == parent) {
                    gp->llink = this;
                }
                else {
                    assert(gp->rlink = parent);
                    gp->rlink = this;
                }
                parent = gp;
            }
            else {
                parent = NULL;
            }

            p->llink = t2;
            if (t2 != NULL) {
                p->llink->parent = p;
            }
            rlink = p;
            rlink->parent = this;
        }

        Node *find(KeyType key) {
            if (this->key == key) {
                return this;
            }
            Node *found = NULL;
            if (llink != NULL) {
                found = llink->find(key);
            }
            if (found == NULL && rlink != NULL) {
                found = rlink->find(key);
            }
            return found;
        }

        void insert(KeyType key, ValueType value) {
            if (key < this->key) {
                if (this->llink == NULL) {
                    this->llink = new Node;
                    this->llink->key = key;
                    this->llink->value = value;
                    this->llink->parent = this;
                } else {
                    this->llink->insert(key, value);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (this->rlink == NULL) {
                    this->rlink = new Node;
                    this->rlink->key = key;
                    this->rlink->value = value;
                    this->rlink->parent = this;
                } else {
                    this->rlink->insert(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Node *root = NULL;

    void splay(Node *x) {
        assert(x != NULL);
        while (x->parent != NULL) {
            if (x->parent->llink == x) {
                x->right_rotate();
            }
            else {
                assert(x->parent->rlink == x);
                x->left_rotate();
            }
        }
        root = x;
    }
    class NodeProxy {
    private:
        map<KeyType, ValueType> *m;
        KeyType key;
    public:
        NodeProxy(map<KeyType, ValueType> *m, KeyType key) : m(m), key(key) {}
        NodeProxy &operator=(ValueType value) {
            m->set(key, value);
            return *this;
        }
        operator ValueType() const{
            return m->get(key);
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, NodeProxy nodeProxy) {
            os << nodeProxy.m->get(nodeProxy.key);
            return os;
        }
    };

public:

    void set(KeyType key, ValueType value) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            root = new Node;
            root->key = key;
            root->value = value;
        }
        else {
            Node *found = root->find(key);
            if (found != NULL) {
                found->value = value;
            } else {
                root->insert(key, value);
            }
        }
    }

    ValueType get(KeyType key) {
        Node *x = root->find(key);
        if (x == NULL) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Key does not exist in the map");
        }
        splay(x);
        return x->value;
    }

    NodeProxy operator[](KeyType key) {
        return NodeProxy(this, key);
    }
};
}

#endif
```

Usage is pretty straight-forward

```
ms::map<std::string, int> reputation;
reputation["Stack Overflow"] = 1422;
reputation["Chemistry"] = 286;
reputation["Code Review"] = 101;
// This question gets down-voted
reputation["Code Review"] = 99;

std::cout << "My reputation on stackoverflow.com is " << reputation["Stack Overflow"] << std::endl;
```

Comment: `I know that std::map uses a BST; I heard it's a Red-Black Tree.`. No you don't know that. The `std::map` has requriments on its access characteristics that lend to its implementation being a BST but there is no requirements in the standard that this is the technique used (though some implementations do use Red-Black trees). But you should make no assumptions on the implementation apart from those imposed by the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to separate the class interface declaration from the implementation. The declaration would serve as a nice overview of the class's functionality, and it's the recommended practice anyway, for information hiding.
This is especially important when you also have inner classes,
and member variables declared in unusual order (between methods),
like `root`.

I suggest to use `K, V` as the template parameter names instead of `KeyType, ValueType`. `K, V` are commonly used and understood as key-value types. When I see `KeyType` without the declaration, my first thought is that it's a `typedef`. But it's actually a template type parameter, which is different. It's confusing.

`llink` and `rlink` are not so good names. By that logic you should suffix all pointers with `link`. I suggest to rename to `left` and `right`, that would be perfectly understandable, and more readable.

I would also rename `left_rotate` and `right_rotate` to `rotate_left` and `rotate_right`. It seems more straightforward, and sound more like actions.

Declare variables closer to where they are actually used.
In this code:

> ```
> Node *t2 = llink;
> Node *p  = parent;
> Node *gp = p->parent;
>
> if (gp != NULL) {
>     if (gp->llink == parent) {
>         gp->llink = this;
>     }
>     else {
>         assert(gp->rlink = parent);
>         gp->rlink = this;
>     }
>     parent = gp;
> }
> else {
>     parent = NULL;
> }
>
> p->rlink = t2;
> if (t2 != NULL) {
>     p->rlink->parent = p;
> }
> llink = p;
> llink->parent = this;
> ```

The declaration and assignment of `t2` is too far from where `t2` is actually used, which seriously hurts readability. It would be better this way:

```
Node *p  = parent;
Node *gp = p->parent;

if (gp != NULL) {
    if (gp->llink == parent) {
        gp->llink = this;
    }
    else {
        assert(gp->rlink = parent);
        gp->rlink = this;
    }
    parent = gp;
}
else {
    parent = NULL;
}

Node *t2 = llink;
p->rlink = t2;
if (t2 != NULL) {
    p->rlink->parent = p;
}
llink = p;
llink->parent = this;
```

Not only it's more readable what is `t2`, now it's clear that it's actually pointless: you could use `llink` directly without `t2`.
Btw, I took a closer look at `t2` because of its poor name.
I was wondering what it does, because its didn't explain anything.
If you had tried to give a more meaningful name to it in the beginning,
something that describes well its purpose,
you probably would have realized yourself early on that it has no purpose.

The variable `p`, being a single letter, is also confusing.
At first look I thought its declaration can be moved down just like `t2`,
I had to look closer to realize that it's important to store the original value of `parent` in it.
If it was named `origParent` or `oldParent`,
this would have been much harder to overlook.

Answer (score 2):

In order of appearance in the code:

### Include files:

Your should always prefer including the C++ headers to the C library.
Therefore, use `<cassert>` instead.

Avoid including `<iostream>` everywhere. You are not even printing inside
the class, so it should not import that dependency. You are indeed using
`std::ostream`, so include [`<ostream>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/).

The proper include to expose `std::runtime_error` is [`<stdexcept>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/).

### Class name:

You have properly wrapped your class in a namespace to be able to use the `map`
name. However, I'm not fully comfortable with your choice. Your class is not
a complete drop-in replacement for `std::map`, so I don't think it is such as good
idea using the same name. Consider naming it `SplayTreeMap` to also make
it clear what type of container this is.

### `NULL`:

`NULL` in C++ is seriously outdated. Switch to [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) today!

### Access level of inner classes:

Shouldn't you make the member variables of `Node` private? It would be better,
no doubt. But then don't just add `get/set` method for them. Make methods
that operate on node data, like `splay()`, members of `Node`.

### `this` to access member data:

You don't have to prefix calls to class methods and member data inside the
class with `this->`. That is quite verbose and unneeded. You should not use it.

### Memory management:

I'm not sure how you are handling memory management at the moment. I've seen
a couple `new`s in there but no `delete`s. C++ is not garbage collected, so
if you don't dispose that memory allocated with `new`, it will stay allocated
until the program terminates. This is a *memory leak*. I don't know if it would
be possible to use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) in this case to automate memory deallocation.
I strongly recommend that you take a look on the smart pointers. If you can't use
any of them, then you will have to keep track of those allocations yourself
and `delete` the pointers somewhere (likely the class destructor).

### Split the class into declaration and implementation:

A popular way of splitting template classes to separate the class
declaration from the template implementation is keeping the declaration in
the `.h` file and placing the implementation in a `.inl` or `.tpl` file.
Most IDEs and editors will recognize those file extensions.
Then you include the implementation file at the end of the header, since the
template must be entirely visible to the user code. Short example:

**MyTemplate.h**:

```
template<class T>
class MyTemplate
{
public:
    void aMethod();
};

#include "MyTemplate.inl"
```

**MyTemplate.inl**:

```
template<class T>
void MyTemplate<T>::aMethod()
{
    // do stuff...
}
```